# Does Flow Networks in Graph Theory includes latency or is it another model?

Tags: graph-theory, network, network-flow

I studied graph theory at the university but "flow networks" were outside the course topics. While reading material about flow networks it is not clear for me if the latency concept (beyond capacity) is there or not. Could you please suggest references on this topic?

I am looking to simulate a computer network with thousands of nodes. While there are software that does this I want to simulate it myself and make it open source. The main obstacle I found with the tools that I know is that they either make the simulation using a lot of real resources from one or more computers or doesn't have the capability to be customized for very specific situations. In this case the graph will have an overlay for a gossip protocol and the graph not only is not fully connected but should follow some rules of connections.